# How can I tell iTunes that a .M4V (movie) is an HD movie?

Tags: itunes, metadata

HD movies that I buy from iTunes appear in iTunes with the movie's name and a little "HD" symbol next to the movie. However, movies I've ripped from my BluRay discs, which are HD, aren't recognized by iTunes as being "HD". Of course they play fine via iTunes or AppleTV, in HD and everything, it's just I'd like to somehow edit the metadata or whatever it is that iTunes uses to identify a movie as being HD. I know it's just cosmetic, but it irritates me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an HD flag you can set in the file's header. You can't set this flag from iTunes.

The best solution on mac is [subler](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler/).

It was updated to support the 1080p value, so you can set the flag to 1 (720p) and 2 (1080p), the only values recognized by iTunes.

You will find the flag in the other settings tab:

[image: Setting the iTunes HD flag]

Comment: Looks like subler ist a gonner. If you click the link all you get is a domain hogger.

Comment: @Martin Indeed you can get it from google code now: http://code.google.com/p/subler/ I don't know for how long though as the download feature is deprecated on google code pages now. I'll keep the link updated.

Comment: Seems to have moved once again:  [bitbucket.org/galad87/subler](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler/wiki/Home)