# iTunes: how can display multiple versions of a movie in SD and 1080p/720p HD as one movie?

Tags: movie, quality, itunes

I want to store the same movie in multiple quality levels. I have 3 files (360p, 720p and 1080p).

[image: Same film at 3 different quality levels]

Obviously having the same movie multiple times in iTunes it not acceptable. I can't fill my library with duplicates.

How should I proceed to make iTunes display the 3 files as one movie? Currently I have 3 movies in iTunes.

[image: 3 movies in iTunes]

I saw a way (adding (HD) to the name of the file) but it doesn't seems to be enough. Adding the HD tag as in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48189/11600) doesn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Subler (http://code.google.com/p/subler/). It open your HD version of the movie in Subler and make sure you check off and mark it as an HD version. This then adds the meta-data so it know's it an HD movie.

Also, make sure it's marked as a Movie. Normally it'll appear as Normal.

Finally, you need to add a meta-tag on the first tab. ContentID needs to be populated, and it has to be unique to your library, and the same for both files. Basically, pick a random number and shove it in.

You can then re-add the movies and it'll bundle them together. At this point you can remove them from iTunes (select and delete). I would choose the Keep Files option, and just drag them back to iTunes to get it re-add them.

Personally, I use iVi (available from the Mac App Store) and if you select the options for both SD and HD output it will do all the work for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but this doesn't help. When I set the right HD tags (none, 720p, 1080p) on the files I end-up with 3 movies (sd, hd, hd) in iTunes. Still not one movie.

Comment: Yes... Actually your edit about the ContentID helped... It was missing in all the files. I created an ID based on a prefix + published date + number that day. And now it works! I have the 3 versions displaying as one movie. Thank you for your help!